# How to make my React Native app to be receiver for open image shared from different apps?

Tags: react-native

How to make my React Native App to be a receiver of image sharing from other apps?
Like Whatsapp, Gmail, Messenger,etc on this picture? Basically any app that has sharing ability but I can't put there my deeplink.

[image]

I already found this for Android:

```
<intent-filter>
     ...
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

and for IOS:extension

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
  <string>com.apple.ui-services</string>
  <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
  <string>MyImageSharingViewController</string>
  <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
    <string>ANY {NSExtensionSupportedImageTypes}</string>
    <key>NSExtensionServiceRoleType</key>
    <string>NSUserActivityService</string>
    <key>NSExtensionServiceAllowsPassingErrors</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
  <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
  <string>TRUEPREDICATE</string>
</dict>
```

But how to proceed to my RN app? Or is this even the good way to go? Thanks for any tips and tricks.